# How do I use vsftp to jail a user to a subdirectory of their home folder

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

How does one configure a user when they login to change root into a subdirectory of their home folder. ie `/home/username/files`

Answer (score 15):

Edit

```
/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Add or change:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/directory
```

Comment: Thanks Tuim that was the ticket

Comment: @SurferJoe Please mark the question as answered for future reference then :)